# Ory Kratos deployment won't start

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, ory, kratos

I have been trying to start an Ory Kratos deployment, but it keeps running into one issue. The pod keeps crashing and when I get the logs, this is the message.

The configuration contains values or keys which are invalid:
identity.schemas.0.url: 
^-- one or more required properties are missing

time=2023-02-25T02:59:14Z level=error msg=Unable to instantiate configuration. audience=application error=map[message:I[#/identity/schemas/0] S[#/properties/identity/properties/schemas/items/required] missing properties: "url"] service_name=Ory Kratos service_version=v0.11.1
Error: I[#/identity/schemas/0] S[#/properties/identity/properties/schemas/items/required] missing properties: "url"

The config file part looks like this.

```
- name: IDENTITY_SCHEMAS
      value: |
        [
          {
            "id": "https://schemas.ory.sh/presets/kratos/identity.email.schema.json",
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
            "title": "Person",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "traits": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "email": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "email",
                    "title": "E-Mail",
                    "ory.sh/kratos": {
                      "credentials": {
                        "password": {
                          "identifier": true
                        }
                      },
                      "recovery": {
                        "via": "email"
                      },
                      "verification": {
                        "via": "email"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "email"
                ],
                "additionalProperties": false
              }
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: shouldn't your `"id": "https://..."` be `"$id", "https://...."` ? See https://www.ory.sh/docs/kratos/concepts/ui-user-interface#node-order-and-labels

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://github.com/ory/kratos/blob/master/contrib/quickstart/kratos/email-password/identity.schema.json) for a working identity schema. You should not need the url for identity schema outside of the hosted Ory Network service.